# Why does pasting a Word table column in VBA result in error 4605 most of the time, then succeed after many attempts?

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I'm using a VBA macro to remove irrelevant rows from a table template in Word. My table has around 100 rows to start with. I noticed that table operations in Word VBA are SLOOOOOW on long tables, so I decided to copy/paste the (few) relevant lines into a new table instead, and delete the original table. This way I only need to copy a handful of lines, rather than deleting nearly 100 lines.

I've run into a quirk that I need help to understand.

When I run the code below on my table, it ALWAYS throws an error 4605 on the second row, on `Newrow.range.paste`. Depending on the sleep duration, the code fails a number of times, to succeed at last. Sleep 500 ms gives 34 fails, 0 ms gives 96 fails, 200 ms gives 66 fails, etc.

```
    For Each OldRow In TestTbl.Rows
        If Models.Contains(OldRow.Cells(1).Range.Text) Then '(meaning it's relevant to copy)
            Set NewRow = NewTbl.Rows(NewTbl.Rows.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            Do
                Err.Clear
                OldRow.Range.Copy
                Sleep 500 'ms
                NewRow.Range.Paste
                If Err <> 0 Then
                    Sleep 200 'ms
                    Debug.Print "Failed to paste row " & OldRow.Index & " from TestTbl with error " & Err & " at " & Now()
                End If
            Loop Until Err = 0
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next OldRow
```

Can someone here help me figure out how to get a paste of the entire row to work on the **first** attempt, not after 30 seconds of trying?

This only happens to the first row that fulfills `if models.contains(Oldrow...text)`. Rows after that get pasted without any errors.

Comment: error 4605 indicates that the problem is at  'NewRow.Range.Copy'. Paste fails because the clipboard is empty. (Probably because the preceding paste had not yet completed) See if specifying the *destination* in the copy command avoids the problem.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the suggestion.
After your input I researched and tried out a way to avoid going via the clipboard altogether. And voila, it works both faster and without bugs...

The relevant code is now:

```
    For Each OldRow In TestTbl.Rows
        If Models.Contains(OldRow.Cells(1).Range.Text) Then
            Set NewRow = NewTbl.Rows(NewTbl.Rows.Count)
            NewRow.Range.FormattedText = OldRow.Range.FormattedText
        End If
    Next OldRow
```

This has tested nicely and is used in production now. It manages to copy merged cells, contentcontrols in cells, formatting, everything. Nice.